# Unable to understand #define in this code

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I have been trying for such code

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    #define minu(x) x*x

    int main() {
    int i=3;
    cout<<minu(i+2);
 // your code goes here
    return 0;
    }
```

and it is giving me output as 11. But I was thinking it should be 25.
Please explain me why this is happening ?

Comment: The macro expands to 3+2*3+2=11. To get the desired result, use `#define minu(x) (x)*(x)`

Comment: change `#define minu(x) x*x` to `#define minu(x) (x)*(x)`

Comment: thanks for the reply

Comment: You can use `g++ -E such_code.cpp > such_code.ii` to see what the result of the macro expansion was: `cout<<i+2*i+2;`. (Or `g++ --save-temps such_code.cpp` and look into the `such_code.ii` file. It contains the preprocessor output.